# Point system and enable and disable buttons in swift programming language

Tags: swift

Hello I want to make a quiz game in swift.I want to disable the 'next' button so that no one can skip to the next question.I tried enabling and disabling buttons in objective c before but its not working in swift.I also want to have a point system in which every correct answer get you 1 point nut I have no idea how to go about to do this.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable a button:

```
myButton.enabled = false
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying (anyobject)->() does not have a member named 'enabled'

Comment: You are talking about buttons. How did you create them? Please edit your post and provide some code.

Comment: `    
    @IBAction func nextbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
        nextbutton.enabled = false
    }`

Comment: This is an action, not an outlet. Create an `@IBOutlet` to your button, give a name and the code I posted in my answer will do.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of this?Also how do I go about implementing a point system in my app?

Comment: Nevermind I got the button enabling part but I still cannot understand how to implement the point system

Answer (score 0):

The above poster is correct, using `button.enabled = false` will disable the button.  To add to that, if you want to hide it (make it invisible to the user), you can toggle this with the `button.hidden` property (e.g. `button.hidden = true` will make the button invisible).

In terms of creating a point system, why not have a variable which holds the points the player has (lets call it `intPoints`).  Every time the player gets a question right, you add one to that variable using `intPoints += 1`.  Similarly, you could subtract points for incorrect answers or taking too long, etc. with `intPoints -= 1`.

If you have multiple view controllers and you want the points variable to be accessible by all of them, make the variable a global one by declaring it outside of a class (for example, if you declare a variable inside a class - that is under the `class ViewController: UIViewController {` line at the top of the swift file, it is accessible by all of the routines within that class.  If you declare it above that line, it will be outside of the class and accessible to all classes).

Then, when you want to present the user with the number of points they have, you can use `label.text = "Congratulations, you finished with \(intPoints) points"` and Xcode will replace `\(intPoints)` with the number of points the player has.

I hope this helps give you a bit more of an understanding. :)

Answer (score -1):

for disabling a button change the next button opacity to 0 if the answer is wrong, in side the right answer validation callback.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail

Comment: Could you please give an example